# Creating a function to apply to every row of several different DFs in r

Tags: r

I have a bunch of gigantic data frames that look something like:

```
   a b c d e f g
  -------------- 
1| 4 3 6 3 7 3 7
2| 4 6 2 5 6 2 1
3| 3 6 2 6 8 1 5
```

I need a function that I can apply to every df but making a rowsum function requires you to include the df name:

```
apf <- function(rowSums(**df**[, c(1, 3, 4, 7)]))
```

How can I make df a variable in the function such that I can run the following for each df:

```
apply(dfn, 1, apf(dfn))
```

and then put the output in a new colun

```
dfn$new_c <- apply(dfn, 1, apf(dfn))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create your function (See my toy example below), you can apply it to a list of your frames:

```
apf <- function(d) {
  d$sums = rowSums(d[, c(1,3,4,7)])
  return(d)
}

dfs = lapply(list(a=a, b=b, c=c),apf)
```

Answer (score -1):

After putting the data frames in a list

```
df_list <- list(A = df, B = df, C = df)
```

```
sapply(df_list, rowSums)
      A  B  C
[1,] 33 33 33
[2,] 26 26 26
[3,] 31 31 31
```

Place any function instead `rowSums` that takes one argument.

##### Data

```
df_list <- list(A = structure(list(a = c(4L, 4L, 3L), b = c(3L, 6L, 6L), 
    c = c(6L, 2L, 2L), d = c(3L, 5L, 6L), e = c(7L, 6L, 8L), 
    f = 3:1, g = c(7L, 1L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), B = structure(list(a = c(4L, 4L, 3L), b = c(3L, 6L, 6L
), c = c(6L, 2L, 2L), d = c(3L, 5L, 6L), e = c(7L, 6L, 8L), f = 3:1, 
    g = c(7L, 1L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), C = structure(list(a = c(4L, 4L, 3L), b = c(3L, 6L, 6L
), c = c(6L, 2L, 2L), d = c(3L, 5L, 6L), e = c(7L, 6L, 8L), f = 3:1, 
    g = c(7L, 1L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))
```